# how to load two jQuery tables at same time or one after another?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to load two jQuery tables at the same time or one after another without conflicting with each other? I tried using `<script></script>` tags to load both tables but it doesn't display any tables and works when I only load either of the tables.

I have to use two tables because, the [1]st table displays the data and the [2]nd does the sorting in the [1]st table.

first table:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#TopPlayedGenresContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Top Played Genres List',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 150,
       sorting: true,
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("TopPlayedGenresList")'
        },
        fields: {
            TrackID: {
                title: 'Track ID',
                tooltip: 'Track Name',
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                resize: false,
            },
            TrackName: {
                title: 'Track Name',
                tooltip: 'Track Name',
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                resize: false,
            },
        }
    });

    $('#TopPlayedGenresContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

second table: 
here's the another table using same `#div` so it can sort the data in it.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#TopPlayedGenresContainer").tablesorter(); 
} 
);
```

html:

```
<div id="TopPlayedGenresContainer" style="height: 498px;"></div>
```

Is it possible to do so? any help would be great help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Deffered Object: [Deffered API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

Comment: thanks for your input.. any chance that you could give an example of it using the `Deferred API`? I'm trying here too but my knowledge with jQuery is below basic.. and thanks again for your help.